# What is the best way to create a Loading Animation for React JS Ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, loading-animation

I have a React JS (16.13.1) application - and I was interested in creating some loading animations to display in the container when that content is being loaded. I was hoping to do it in a way that could provide some reusability like the following example:

```js
import React from "react";
...
import axios from "axios";
import LoadingAnimation from "[myloadinganimation]"

class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { widgets: [] };
    }

    getWidgets() {
        const data = new FormData();
        return axios.post('/my/api/url', data, window.globals.formPostHeaders)
               .then(res => {
                    const regions = res.data.regions.map(obj => obj);
                    this.setState({regions});
               });
        
    }


    render() {
         return (
              <>
                 <Table>
                     <tbody>
                     <tr>
                         <!-- desired component -->
                         <LoadingAnimation self={this} conds={{obj: this, cb: 'callback?'}} />
                         <!-- /desired component -->
                     </tr>
                     </tbody>
                 </Table>
              <>
         );

    }

}
```

In theory, what I would have is a component called LoadingAnimation that can be invoked on this page - preferably on page load, or even just whenever an AJAX request is kicked off. I realize that it would require some combination of listeners, callbacks and Promise's to do this. I just cannot figure out the right flow/order for this to appear.

For this to be reusable, I would have the component display the animation, do the listening for the completion of the ajax request, and then pass the data to the **callback** in the view component for rendering; so as to abstract the lifting away from the Animation component, but handling dispatching of the events or whatever they may be.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get the reusable part. The most straight forward approach to handle loading is to take care of it in the state (as it is shown below). I don't know if it is resuable for you :

```
class Widget extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { widgets: [], loading : false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // to trigger on page load
    this.getWidgets()
  }

  async getWidgets() {
    this.setState({ loading: true})
    const data = new FormData();
    await axios.post('/my/api/url', data, window.globals.formPostHeaders)
      .then(res => {
        const regions = res.data.regions.map(obj => obj);
        this.setState({ regions });
      });
    this.setState({ loading : false})
  }


  render() {
    return (
            <>
              <Table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    { this.state.loading && <LoadingAnimation />}
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            <>
          );
       }
}
```

If you wanna re-use this in different places, you better search for a way to spread the loading state around components and places you wanna re-use. You may use redux or flux libraries to handle state for such cases. There is also built-in Context API which might be useful too.

Comment: My thoughts were, it would just be a component i could inject into any area that populated with Ajax (paginators, initial page load, etc) - so that the component could dispatch the requests to whatever to render it when the request completes

Comment: @BarryChapman component that watches the loading states will be enough for such use. It can be Redux container component that using loading state as a prop.

Comment: Shouldn't the `this.setState({ loading: false })` be inside the promise.then()?

Comment: It can fall into catch() that you forgot to write. So in case of fail request, it will keep loading.